# html post form won't send data when action is set

Tags: php, html, forms

When `action=""` is not set like that the form will send the data entered and store it in the database.

However when I use `action="order.php"` to redirect once the form has been submitted it does not send the data to database.

I've deleted the database information I haven't missed it out

Here's my **PHP** code:

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>
<?php 
include('inc/header.php'); 
?>

<?php 
include('inc/nav.php'); 
?>


    <div>

    <?php

        if (!empty($_POST))  {

             $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=;charset=utf8', '', '');

             $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (first_name, last_name, email,                 address_line_1, address_line_2, city, postcode)
     values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");


             $first_name  = $_POST["firstname"];
             $last_name = $_POST["lastname"];
             $email = $_POST["email"];
             $address_line_1 = $_POST["address1"];
             $address_line_2 = $_POST["address2"];
             $city = $_POST["city"];
             $postcode = $_POST["postcode"];

             $stmt->bindParam(1, $first_name);
             $stmt->bindParam(2, $last_name);
             $stmt->bindParam(3, $email);
             $stmt->bindParam(4, $address_line_1);  
             $stmt->bindParam(5, $address_line_2);
             $stmt->bindParam(6, $city);    
             $stmt->bindParam(7, $postcode);        

             $success = $stmt->execute();  

             $orderplaced = 'order.php';

             if ($success) { 

             }
             else { 

                 print "not successful"; 
             } 
     }
?>
```

And the **HTML:**

```
    <form action="order.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
              <legend> <h2>Checkout</h2></legend>
                  <ul class="checkout">

                      <li><label>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your last name" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>Address Line 1: <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Enter your address" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>Address Line 2: <input type="text" name="address2" placeholder="Enter your address" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>City: <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter your city" required/></label></li>

                      <li><label>Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode" maxlength="10" placeholder="Enter your postcode" required/></label></li>

                      <li><input type="submit" name="submit"/> </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>

<?php 
include('inc/footer.php'); 
?>
```

Comment: what is there in order.php?

Comment: is all of this code on your `order.php` file?

Comment: Do you want to submit the form to its own page?

Comment: No it's in a different file. I've posted order.php in edit

Comment: When in development, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Whoever edited this removed the my order.php

Comment: @user3617311 you can bring it back by editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:
1) remove the action of the form and let the form be submitted to itself so the submitted data will be saved in DB, and then redirect it to `order.php`

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

Then on sucess

```
if ($success) { 
   header('location: /order.php');
}
```

2) Copy all the submit php section you have to `order.php` and let the form as is

Comment: Calm down there. Doesn't let me yet

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i haven't understood well your question, but if your actions redirect to "order.php", there must be your database connection and there you have to check your $_POST and do your inserts.

Comment: Yes, but you are checking your $_POST in the other

Comment: No I'm not. I got an answer but thanks for your input

Answer (score 0):

This is because the part of code that stores the form to the Database is at the current location (which seems not to be order.php right?)

when specifying "order.php" you make the client send his form to this page.
What you want is redirecting after having saved all these datas.

or, you can put the part of code accessing your DB in 'order.php'

Answer (score 0):

Copy your PHP from the first page and place it on your redirect page

Answer (score 0):

action can be use as PHP_SELF

http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-action-self.html